# Why does tomato sauce spatter more than other sauces?

Tags: food-science, tomatoes

Of all the (thick) sauces and creams I prepare in a hot pot, tomato sauce is the most jumpy.

When it's hot, it's impossible to cook properly without having it jump everywhere and repaint the walls, and in general the surroundings.

Of course, using a lid helps to solve the problem, but I'm curious:

**Why is a hot tomato sauce so prone to jump out of the pot and repaint everything around?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Short answer: tomato sauce is a [non-Newtonian fluid](http://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/Science-Stories/Strange-Liquids/Non-Newtonian-fluids). Another interesting link can be found [here](http://scienceinavan.blogspot.com/2012/05/non-newtonian-tomatoes.html).

Tomato sauce is an interesting creature. Think about ketchup. You try to shake some out and nothing happens. So you tap the bottle a little bit, still nothing. Tap it a little harder, and a little harder, and suddenly **boom**: a flood of ketchup. The "jumpiness" of tomato sauce is caused by the same physics.

Basically, tomato sauce has two things in it that contribute to this characteristic: water and tomato pulp. At first, the tomato pulp is just lying around every which way, which makes the sauce act a lot thicker. But when the strands of pulp are aligned, it makes the sauce act a lot more like water. Heating up the sauce increases the pressure on the sauce, allowing areas of the sauce to become much more fluid, resulting in bubbling, popping, and the flinging of tomato sauce all over your clean white shirt. The same effect is what makes ketchup come flying out of the bottle - when you whack it hard enough, the pressure changes the state of the ketchup, and the ketchup literally flows like water.

**Edit**: updated with relevant information

Unfortunately, when I managed to get a hold of Mr. Steingarten's lovely book, [The Man Who Ate Everything](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375702024),* I discovered that the passage regarding tomato sauce as a non-Newtonian fluid was exclusively regarding *ketchup*, and not general tomato sauce as I thought I remembered. However, this description is still a valuable one, and it does help explain this particular characteristic of tomato-based sauces (after all, ketchup is a tomato based sauce) [p 96]:

> It was only after I had send a stream of ketchup streaking across my
>   wife's favorite tablecloth, a lovely hand-printed Indian cotton from a
>   shop on the rue Jacob, that I telephoned Professor Malcolm Bourne at
>   Cornell for a lesson in non-Newtonian fluids. Sir Isaac Newton wrote
>   the laws governing liquids that flow like water: the more force you
>   exert on them, the faster they flow. But ketchup is different.
>   Composed of tangled red tomato fibers suspended in a sweet and acidic
>   colorless serum, ketchup behaves like a solid both at rest and under
>   low levels of pressure: but then, at some higher threshold, it
>   suddenly begins flowing like an ordinary fluid. That's why the
>   frustrated ketchup lover who loses patience with gentle taps on the
>   bottle's bottom and prematurely shifts to a powerful wallop ends up
>   with a gush of ketchup over everything. Ketchup and mayonnaise are
>   known as Bingham fluids, named after the scientist who characterized
>   them early [last] century.

<sub><sub>*Personally, I think that *The Man Who Ate Everything* is a must-read for anyone interested in culinary science, and a should-read for anyone interested in food.</sub></sub>

**Second Edit**:
Due to a handful of downvotes that I received while I slept last night, I guess some clarification is needed:

1. I just want to be absolutely clear here, I am in no way implying that `ketchup == tomato sauce`. I offer this information as an example of how tomato pulp suspended in liquid acts.
2. The fact that "tomato sauce is thick" doesn't really hold up. The question even clearly states: *"Of all the sauces and creams I prepare in a hot pot, **tomato sauce is the most jumpy**"*, which presumably includes thick ones. If thickness was the only factor (and I'm not saying that it isn't a factor), we would see similar actions from cheese sauces, bechamels, gravies, and a variety of soups. While these sauces/soups *do* splatter, tomato sauce is significantly more "splattery." Put a pot of tomato sauce next to any other sauce/soup, take your pick, and heat them to the same temperature. I can pretty much guarantee that given similar conditions, you're going to be wiping up a lot more tomato sauce than the other one.

**One last edit**:
[This article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2012/12/13/why_does_tomato_sauce_splatter_when_it_cooks.html) on Slate indicates that it's a combination of the above (being a "plastic liquid"), the viscosity, and pectin, as pointed out by Brendan in a comment below.

Comment: ketchup is what is known as a fluid gel in the culinary world. With force it behaves like a fluid but left alone it behaves like a gel.

Comment: @Brendan Hmm. I've never heard that before, and I was a professional cook for years. Learn something new every day. I guess I'm just too much of a physics nerd, I always refer to it as a "Non-Newtonian fluid."

Comment: @Gnoupi No problem. If you're into food science, you should definitely read that book. My former chef bought me a copy for my first competition, and it really changed the way I look at food. And it's entertaining as well.

Comment: I will give it a look, indeed, seems interesting

Comment: I like that book a lot too. Definitely makes you think about him in a different way instead of the curmudgeon on tv. @Mong134 you may be right in it's most scientific of terms though. They have a nice write up about fluid gels in the modernist cuisine books. I made one the other day for a dinner, they're very cool!

Comment: He's on TV? I had no idea.

Comment: Is it actually necessary for a fluid to be non-newtonian to be really splattery, or just sufficiently viscous but without much surface tension to pull things back when they try to break away from the surface?

Comment: @Jefromi I don't think it's a *required* characteristic for a fluid to be splattery. It just makes it significantly more so. Put a pan of alfredo sauce and a pan of tomato sauce on the stove. You'll see a significant difference.

Comment: I don't think that comparison really demonstrates this - alfredo sauce has much more surface tension than tomato sauce, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jefromi you're right, I didn't read that comment closely enough. Replace alfredo sauce with veal demi glace. Or a sauce thickened with roux versus a sauce thickened with a cornstarch slurry.

Comment: 'non-Newtonian' is a huge category.  Both sheer thinning (ketchup) and sheer thickening (thick starch mixtures) fluids qualify, as do other fluids & gels that behave abormally such as Bingham plastics (toothpaste).

Comment: @Joe that's why it's the short answer. :-)

Comment: -1 this answer is incorrect.  The main reason is due to the thickness of the sauce; the fact that the sauce is non-newtonian has little to do with it *(we could easily have a non-newtonian fluid that didn't spatter this much; or a newtonian fluid that did)*.  See @Jefromi's and my answers.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft if that were the case, then cheese based sauces, bechamels, and gravies would splatter *everywhere*. And tomato sauce is significantly "splashier" than other sauces.

Comment: @Mong134 I think you're underestimating how low the effective surface tension of something like tomato sauce is. With all the little particles of tomato in there, it can't even form bubbles at the surface - when steam reaches the surface it just goes straight out. With all the examples you gave, there's enough resistance to have a big effect. All that aside, tomato sauce doesn't even exhibit the same behavior as ketchup. You can pour it straight out of a jar or pot. There's no sudden transition from solid-ish to flowing.

Comment: You might want to clean up your answer so that it says what it means at the top, rather than reading like a list of corrections to your first version. That said, despite the Slate article and your further edits, I still am unsure how much a factor this "plastic fluid" thing can be - the simple fact is that tomato sauce pours and flows pretty well. If there is some initial resistance to motion, it's *very* small.

Comment: I even heard some tomato sauces have thixotropy ... sounds sciencey enough :)

Answer (score 13):

This is generally true of thick sauces, particularly ones with low surface tension. When thick sauces boil, there's plenty of resistance to the bubbles rising, so they get bigger before they leave the bottom of the pot. When the bubbles do reach the surface and burst, they're big enough to throw sauce everywhere.

Since there's basically no surface tension (force along the surface, resisting perturbation), the rising bubble just goes straight through and throws stuff everywhere. If on the other hand you were boiling a very thick sugar syrup, you wouldn't get much splatter at all - it sticks to itself, and doesn't let bits fly off when the bubbles break the surface. Other sauces this thick have far more surface tension - for example, a thick gravy or cheese sauce, or even a sugar syrup.

Also, since the sauce is thick, the droplets don't disintegrate as much in the air, and they travel farther, so they less frequently fall back into the pot. It's especially noticeable with something as colored as tomato sauce.

Often it's better to simmer sauces than to boil them anyway, so you can avoid it even without a lid.

Comment: Yes, but compared to other thick sauces even, tomato seems to behave particularly worse, like exploding more, and sending much more things around.

Comment: I also think we're dealing with the fact that tomatoes, being fruit, are going to have a lot of pectin released when cooked and this is going to be a more goopy mess than say a cheese sauce where your maybe only dealing with the viscosity of the sauce.

Comment: @Brendan I'm not sure I follow - you say it's not just viscous but also "goopy". What does goopy mean besides viscosity? Tomato sauce *definitely* doesn't have enough pectin to start gelling or anything.

Comment: I mean goopy as in tomato sauce tends to bubble in many small spots where the tomatoes almost congeal like little volcanos where the overall viscosity of a cheese sauce tends to bubble slower but in bigger bubbles because it acts more elastic.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it being a fruit has to do with it: when I had blender that wasn't very good I used to have to make purees with a lot of liquid added and them reduce them down on the stove, I remember celeriac in particular being particularly violent in giving off splatters.

Comment: If it was just pectin, you could see this behavior with jam. Instead I see it mostly with root vegetables, e.g. celeriac as per @Stefano. I personally suspect soluble fiber, but I have no evidence.